# How can I fix the regex to validate an image link with multiple periods

Tags: html, regex, image

Currently the regex only validates simple HTML image links that end in .jpg .jpeg .png and .gif

Is there a simple way to modify the following regex expression to accept links such as  i.imgur.com/____.extension or links that are separated by multiple periods such as an image from a site/forum like wikipedia.

For example how can I alter the current regex to accept a link like this? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/The_river_effect_in_justified_text.jpg

The current regex expression is:

```
 ([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jp$g|png|gif)$)
```

And I know that I can use this to check for characters that match any of the characters inside of [].

```
[a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.
```

Here is the segment in question that I am trying to accept a regex expression for an image for. Previously this was the regex for

custonValidation:customRegexp = " ([a-z-_0-9/:.]*.(jp$g|png|gif)$)"

```
 <com.andreabaccega.widget.FormEditText
            customValidation:testType="regexp"
            customValidation:customRegexp="^((?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/(?:[^\s/]*/)*)([^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$"
            customValidation:emptyAllowed="true"
            customValidation:testErrorString="This is not a valid URL"
            android:id="@+id/edit_imgpath_entry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I understand most of the basics of regex expressions but I am just unsure how to extend it to accept more complicated cases.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why not just do `\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$`?

Comment: Not just that....why can't you just check the end of the string? Are you trying to extract image URLs from a paragraph of text?

Answer (score 0):

You need some type of URL validation before the image.

I guess you could do that with this

\x{} notation : `^((?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))|localhost))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/(?:[^\s/]*/)*)([^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$`

"" stringed : `"^((?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{a1}-\\x{ffff}]{2,})))|localhost))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:/(?:[^\\s/]*/)*)([^/]+\\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$"`

\u notation : `^((?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/(?:[^\s/]*/)*)([^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$`

"" stringed : `"^((?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))|localhost))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:/(?:[^\\s/]*/)*)([^/]+\\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$"`

Formatted - Readable version :

```
 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start), Domain
      (?! mailto: )
      (?:
           (?: https? | ftp )
           ://
      )?
      (?:
           \S+ 
           (?: : \S* )?
           @
      )?
      (?:
           (?:
                (?:
                     [1-9] \d? 
                  |  1 \d\d 
                  |  2 [01] \d 
                  |  22 [0-3] 
                )
                (?:
                     \.
                     (?: 1? \d{1,2} | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-5] )
                ){2}
                (?:
                     \.
                     (?:
                          [1-9] \d? 
                       |  1 \d\d 
                       |  2 [0-4] \d 
                       |  25 [0-4] 
                     )
                )
             |  (?:
                     (?: [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ -? )*
                     [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ 
                )
                (?:
                     \.
                     (?: [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ -? )*
                     [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+ 
                )*
                (?:
                     \.
                     (?: [a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,} )
                )
           )
        |  localhost
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?: : \d{2,5} )?
 (?:                           # Directory's
      / 
      (?: [^\s/]* / )*
 )
 (                             # (2 start), The image
      [^/]+ \.
      (?: jpe?g | png | gif )
 )                             # (2 end)
 $
```

Sample output :

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 90 ) 
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/The_river_effect_in_justified_text.jpg  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 : len 28 ) 
https://upload.wikimedia.org  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 52 : len 38 ) 
The_river_effect_in_justified_text.jpg
```

Comment: @SOEN_student - There might be, but I'm afraid you'd be out of the URI spec. And, I wouldn't attempt that. The regex may look big, but it is fast as lightning. Are you afraid of large regexes ? Use http://www.regexformat.com app to manage your fears.

Comment: @SOEN_student - Crashed ? No error messages ? What kind of language are you running this in ? If it's Java, most double quotes strings need to be escaped. The regex's in my answer are _raw_, what the regex engine expects to see. To put it into a language it should be escaped first. Updated my answer.